# Getting a Exception java.lang.NullPointerException. Cant figure out why

Tags: java, exception, null

First post on here. But im having some issues with what i thought would be a simple "program" to write.

Its a program that takes a .text file and organizes it by "player" number. The players are baseball players, and are listen by Player Number(The number on the back of their jerseys).

This is the fileMenuHandler File

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
public class FileMenuHandler implements ActionListener {
   JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
public FileMenuHandler (JFrame jf) {
   jframe = jf;}
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
  String  menuName = event.getActionCommand();
  File fileName = null;
  if (menuName.equals("Open"))
     readSource(fileName); 
  else if (menuName.equals("Quit"))
     System.exit(0);} //actionPerformed

private void openFile( ) {
   JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser( );
   int status;
   status = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
   chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
   chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
   if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
      readSource(chooser.getSelectedFile());
   else 
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Open File dialog canceled");
} //openFile

private void readSource(File chosenFile) {
   String chosenFileName = chosenFile.getName();
   TextFileInput inFile = new TextFileInput(chosenFileName);
   String names;
   int subscript = 0;
   TextArea myTextArea = new TextArea();
   TextArea mySubscripts = new TextArea();
   names = inFile.readLine();
   while (names != null) {
      mySubscripts.append(Integer.toString(subscript++)+"\n");
      myTextArea.append(names+"\n");
      names = inFile.readLine();
   } //while
 jframe.setVisible(true);  
 }}
```

Im getting errors at:

```
String chosenFileName = chosenFile.getName();
File fileName = null;
```

I feel like its a really stupid mistake but i need some pointers.
All help will be much appreciated, feel free to make fun of me :) lol

ERROR LOG:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at FileMenuHandler.readSource(FileMenuHandler.java:32)
at FileMenuHandler.actionPerformed(FileMenuHandler.java:14)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuItemUI.doClick(AquaMenuItemUI.java:157)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Can you past the error that you are facing

Comment: @Touchacid...are you able to get through it as per the pointers given in answers? Please accept the solution as answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @Garry Im trying to get the Filename to be fulfilled when i chose a text file by browsing to it through a dialog box using JFileCooser, and passing the name to FileName...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because of these lines :

```
File fileName = null;
  if (menuName.equals("Open"))
     readSource(fileName);
```

Here you have set filename as null and you are using that `filename` in another method.

like : `String chosenFileName = chosenFile.getName();`

that will cause `NullPointerException`

A simple fix would be assign a file object to this variable. like :

```
File file=new File(<pathtofile>);
```

Comment: I understand thus far, what i cant seem to get is how to fix it :O What i want to do is give the name of the file to fileName? am i correct?

Comment: simply assign a File object to this variable like :`File file=new File(<pathtofile>);`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting null file name at this line:

```
File fileName = null;
  if (menuName.equals("Open"))
     readSource(fileName);
```

This is causing Null pointer exception.

Instead you should provide the file name from which you are reading. For example:

```
File fileName = new File("/path-to-file/hello.txt");
```

Comment: I would like it to open a Dialogue which lets me choose the file, rather than an arbitrary preset destination file.     TO ALL: THANK YOU FOR THE FAST RESPONSES, YOU GUYS ARE GREAT.